# FormBuilderFilterChip: align the chips on the same line

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display the created chips on the same line with a horizontal scroll. any idea how to do it with FormBuilderFilterChip ?

Edit: I found how to solve my problem, so I hope the updated code will be useful to other people

```
return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: widget.onRefresh ?? () async {},
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                BlocBuilder<ItemCategoriesBloc, ItemCategoriesState>(
                  builder: ((context, state) {
                    if (state is ItemCategoriesLoadedState) {
                      List<MapEntry<int, Category>> categoryList =
                          List.from(state.categories.entries);
                      return Container(
                        width: 800,
                        child: FormBuilderChoiceChip(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                          selectedColor: MyTheme.primary,
                          alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          direction: Axis.horizontal,
                          initialValue: categoryList.map((value) => value).toList(),
                          name: 'filter_category',
                          options: categoryList
                              .map(
                                (category) => FormBuilderFieldOption(
                                  value: category.value.id,
                                  child: Text(category.value.name),
                                ),
                              )
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return Container();
                  }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Have you got answer?

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri I did but it is not really helpful. I tried an other approach but now I have new problems

Comment: Should I share it here or do I need to open another topic ?

Comment: Update the code, that should be enough

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps :)

```
Expanded(
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
     scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
       child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
              //your BlocBuilder etc etc etc..
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your help, I already tried that and get this error: The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Comment: The widget you trying to use probably uses Flexible or Expanded in is build code, all you gotta do is to delete that flexible or expanded.